# How to call a zend controller action from an independent php file?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having a controller IndexController.php in which action is something like this

```
class IndexController extends CustomControllerAction {


public function preDispatch() {


    if (!$this->view->authenticated) {


        $this->_redirect('/users/login');


    }


}

public function indexemailAction() {

  //somecode which calculates certain things

}
```

}

NOw,I need to call the action "indexmailAction" inside the IndexController.php with  an independent php file

The php file is indextest.php

```
 <?php
   //Need to write some code to call indexmailAction in IndexController.php

 ?>
```

What should I write in this file ......

Thanks in advance

Comment: You create helper and call it any where

Comment: what do you mean by "independent php file" ? a model ? a view ? another controller ? or is it not even in the same application ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years old, and this may not be the intended use of the classes/functions, but I've found the following quite useful in isolated files that are called from the command line.

The problem this solves for me is that it eliminates spawning of Apache processes. The solution is great because I can access the some Controller/Action needed that I would from the URL.

In almost any ZF1 based app, you can copy your index file and keep everything the same and just comment out the following line.

```
$application->run();
```

Anything below this line you can access with your autoloaders etc. It's crude, but it works. Unfortunately, you'll soon find yourself with limited access to a lot of the files your application has, and the feeling the only way you can access the files needed is through a Controller/Action.

Instead, I use the following in a new file below $application->bootstrap() ( still removing the $application->run() ):

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

// You can put more here if you use non-default modules
$front->setControllerDirectory(array(
        'default' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/controllers'
));

$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setNeverRender(true);

Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

$req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http("http://anydomain.tld/controller/action");

// Example just to see how this can be extended
$req->setParam("someVar", "someValue");

$front->setRequest($req);

$front->dispatch();
```

In the end you have a isolated PHP file that bootstraps everything the same as your main index.php for the web, but you can manually trigger a controller/action as needed, giving you easier access to the rest of the files with how ZF1 intended you to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are designed to be used in an MVC, not by scripts. Your controller should assemble request variables, direct them to models and return an HTTP response of some sort. Your scripts should act directly on the models instead.

Anyhow, if you insist, you can instantiate a controller class and call methods just like any other class as long as you inject any dependencies that the MVC would have.

Comment: Than you very much.Independent file in the sense means to a file which is not inside the application.It will be a .php file.This file should invoke an action either from controller or model....

Comment: How would I do this by directly invoking from model?

Comment: You don't, it's not meant to operate like that. So if you want to do it, you'll need to figure it out yourself because you won't find a blog post telling you how to do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to call a controller action for this, your logic should reside in your models. Then you can create a new instance of your model and invoke the appropriate methods. example :

```
require_once '/path/to/mymodel.php';
$mymodel = new Mymodel();
$data = $mymodele->fetchAll();
```

PS: Maybe you should think of creating a restful api to handle calls from outside your application

**UPDATE**:

ok, I see now what you need, The best way to achieve it is to call a url instead of a file (e.g. website.com/emails/send), if you are worried about security you can use some preshared key to make sure the request comes from you, send it with the request and check if it's correct in your action.

Comment: Actually,I need to make auto email feature in which email should go daily at  a particular time.All logics are included in my controller.Thats why I am little bit confused..I have written all the necessary queries in mapper.Do I need to write inside model or mapper..I am not sure about this..thanks

Comment: How to do this with in the model?This is a part of zend.If I call a core php file like indexTest.php, how would this work?

Comment: require_once '/path/to/mymodel.php';
$mymodel = new Mymodel();
$data = $mymodele->fetchAll();   what should I include in  '/path/to/mymodel.php'?

Comment: Thank you very much..what u have said was right.Any ways,I have done it by writing it in a seperate file

Answer (score 0):

If you want logic used in multiple places in your actions, then it should go in an action helper or if very generic code, then in a custom library (/library/custom/)

NB: The authentication would be better suited in a plugin rather than the pre-dispatch method in every controller.